# What is the diffrence between backoffLimit and startingDeadlineSeconds in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Note that a job's `.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` takes precedence over its `.spec.backoffLimit`. Therefore, a job that is retrying one or more failed pods will not deploy additional pods once it reaches the time limit specified by `activeDeadlineSeconds`, even if the `backoffLimit` is not yet reached.

Answer (score 0):

say, if the job is failed you might want kubernetes to rerun the job.
spec.backoffLimit is used to specify the number of retries before considering a Job as failed. The back-off limit is set by default to 6. You can overwrite it.

By default, a Job will run uninterrupted unless a Pod fails  or a Container exits in error , at which point the Job defers to the .spec.backoffLimit described above. Once .spec.backoffLimit has been reached the Job will be marked as failed and any running Pods will be terminated.

Another way to terminate a Job is by setting an active deadline. Do this by setting the .spec.activeDeadlineSeconds field of the Job to a number of seconds. The activeDeadlineSeconds applies to the duration of the job, no matter how many Pods are created. Once a Job reaches activeDeadlineSeconds, all of its running Pods are terminated and the Job status will become type: Failed with reason: DeadlineExceeded.

Note that a Job's .spec.activeDeadlineSeconds takes precedence over its .spec.backoffLimit. Therefore, a Job that is retrying one or more failed Pods will not deploy additional Pods once it reaches the time limit specified by activeDeadlineSeconds, even if the backoffLimit is not yet reached.